# Is it possible to visit the Vatican while wearing a Hijab?

Tags: legal, religion, islam, vatican-city

I have read the question "[Is there a dress code when visiting the Vatican in Rome?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6316/is-there-a-dress-code-when-visiting-the-vatican-in-rome)" carefully and I thought "the better covered the more welcomed" just like the photo suggested.

[image]

However the question has not discussed the Islamic clothing ie Hijab and/or veil and [this tripadvisor review](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g187793-d191000-r148268207-Vatican_Museums-Vatican_City_Lazio.html) freaked me out.

Comment: hijab or niqab? Hijab is more like a nun and unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: @KateGregory I don't know your definition for Niqab but for us Arabs Niqab is covering the face. My wife covers her face most of the time but she has to live with covering only her head sometimes. Like when she goes to the school to check pick up our son as they don't allow people to cover their faces there. So let's say that she'll be covering her head only with a Hijab

Comment: that's also my definition. I asked because the review mentioned "veil" a few times, but you only said hijab. Since there are such things as Catholic veils, the trip advisor review seems illogical to me and it's wise not to just take that one reviewer's word for it.

Comment: Similarly as to how women have to cover up before entering the blue mosque, women might have to uncover their head/face to enter saint Peter's basilica. Frankly I see no problem there. Don't want to uncover? Don't go visiting certain places. Having said this I couldn't find any authoritative sources on the matter.

Comment: @JoErNanO your comment is not an answer to my question, seriously you want me to go there just to find out that we are not allowed and I have to go back home? it would be great to know beforehand you know.

Comment: I highly doubt whether they would make your wife remove her hijab to let her enter the Basilica.

Comment: From the tour: _This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat._ and _Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer._

Comment: Why don't email the staff for answer

Comment: Related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7612/do-i-have-to-be-catholic-to-visit-the-vatican-city

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Note that the sign is specifically for St. Peter's Basilica, and not Vatican City. A small point considering the size of the place, but you have asked about Vatican City.*

If she is wearing the *Hijab* then there will be no issues; covering of the head/hair is common as a sign of respect (for women, for men, its opposite - you can't wear hats); and as mentioned in the comments she will be in good company as many nuns also cover their body save for the face.

If she is wearing the *Niqab* (face veil) you may have an issue - but it will have to do with security more than any religious sensitivities.

Of course, if you are visiting many of the [museums in the Vatican City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_Museums) you will not have such stringent requirements.

Comment: For men too, wearing certain styles of headgear is certainly appropriate. But wearing a sombrero might be frowned upon ;0